# Is there a way to staticly analys references of a plugin.xml

Tags: java, static, rcp, analysis

So im currently working on a very old project written in Java for the eclipse plattform. Unfortunately there is a lot of code and presumably there is a lot of unused code and also a lot of bad habits inside. So what i wanted to do is run a static code analysis. But in RCP there is a lot of references being called from the framework using the plugin.xml.

Is there a way to have these references still being part of the analysis?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com), it detects all the dependencies and you can create custom queries usinq [CQLinq](https://www.jarchitect.com/cqlinq) to filter what you want to check as dependencies.